# Using fileReader.readAsDataURL to transport image through Ajax in Django and open in PIL

Tags: ajax, json, django, python-imaging-library

Few days can't fight problem. I need to transport image through AJAX as JSON. I encoded it as base64 by using `fileReader.readAsDataURL`, and transport that. But PIL won't open it. Here is my code:

script.js:

```
function imageloader(callBack){
var input = $('#photo');
var file = input.prop('files')[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(){
    callBack(reader.result);

};
reader.readAsDataURL(file);

$('#edit_form').submit(function (eve) {
    eve.preventDefault();
    var form = $.toJSON($(this).serializeArray());
    imageloader(function(image){
        var image_data = $.toJSON(image);
        sender(form,image_data);
    });
});
```

view.py:

```
def post(self, request):
    form = request.POST.get('form')
    image = request.POST.get('image')
    new_image = json.loads(image)
    data = json.loads(form)
    new_data = {}
    for i in data:
        new_data[i['name']] = i['value']
    new_data['photo'] = resize_picture(new_image)
...
def resize_picture(file):
    file = file.split(',')[1]
    bytes = (BytesIO(base64.b64decode(file)))
    bytes.seek(0)
    image = bytes.read()
    img = Image.open(image)
    img.thumbnail(IMAGE_SIZE, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    return img
```

Every time I try it I get this error from PIL trying to open the file:

```
 file() argument 1 must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str
```

Did i miss something?

Comment: even if i saving "image" before opening in PIL. it saves like normal pictures. But PIL still don't want to read it. Of Course I can save it like file, and open like file. But it looks really ugly.

Answer (score 2):

The filereader.readAsDataURL function produces a data URL which is a unicode string of the form "data:[image type];[encoding],[THEENCODEDSTUFF....]".

To process it in python and possibly assign it to an image field, cherry pick from my code snippet below (the uploaded data is on the variable url_data and the imagefield on the django model object is obj.avatar_image):

```
    img_dict = re.match("data:(?P<type>.*?);(?P<encoding>.*?),(?P<data>.*)", url_data).groupdict()
    blob = img_dict['data'].decode(img_dict['encoding'], 'strict')
    image = Image.open(StringIO(blob))
    image = image.resize((75, 75), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    f = StringIO()
    try:
        image.save(f, format='png')
        filename = os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + '.png'
        obj.avatar_image.save(filename, ContentFile(f.getvalue()))
    finally:
            f.close()
```